# Can I catch the event of exiting a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, listener

currently I use DocumentListener and when I enter "11111"
I get 5 events.

I want 1 event when user exits the field.

Comment: May be this link can help you http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [focus listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) on the textfield itself.

```
field.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println("User entered " + field.getText());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a [FocusListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html).

Answer (score 2):

> currently I use DocumentListener and when I enter "11111" I get 5 events.

Sounds like you are trying to validate the data in the text field when you lose focus.

If this is the case then use an InputVerifier. The API has a working example.